# I don't understand event sourcing

Tags: microservices, grpc, event-sourcing

I'm new to event sourcing and have some question on my mind. [Here example diagram.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFO5z.png)

1. Let say we have 2 instances of service BookShop and 2 instances of service Wallet.
   User ask BookService_1 to buy him a book. This book service creates event BuyBookRequestCreated and push it to event bus. Event bus emits this event to two instances of service Wallet. Two instances now try to reserve enough money from user wallet and they both emit event BookMoneyReserved? Now on the other side two instances of BookShop services recive 2 events and they both try to emit event BookBought? Or maybe eventbus will send BuyBookRequestCreated to only one subscriber? But then what happends when this selected service fails?
2. How this pattern is handlen from API consumer point of view? If I make call to some API to buy me a book I expect it to "return 200" when the book is bought. In event sourcing pattern there is no awaiting for response from other services so in case if some other service must emit an event to complete book purchase there is no way of telling the customer if his purchase actually faild or not.
3. I'm a little lost in the whole microservice world. On one hand we have Grpc, protobufs and service mesh but on the other we have event sourcing and event driven architecture. When to use which? And from what I see and can understand I could use event sourcing and grpc togheter? I could just use grpc to communicate beetwen services and save events as a form of state persistance or maybe I just completly didn't get it and should read thru articles again?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Event-driven integration is not Event Sourcing. Check this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=STKCRSUsyP0 and maybe https://www.eventstore.com/blog/what-is-event-sourcing and some of our past webinars https://www.eventstore.com/webinars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't understand event sourcing

That's not your fault.  The literature sucks.

> Here example diagram.

OK, so the most important lesson I can give you about that diagram: it has nothing to do with *event sourcing*.  It has quite a bit to do with *messaging*, and *distributed systems*, and *event driven*.  But event sourcing is a different animal.

At the high level, a fundamental concern is that distributed systems are imperfect.  So we need to accept that as a constraint in our designs, and work with it.  Pat Helland's [Memories, Guesses, and Apologies](https://web.archive.org/web/20100722052618/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pathelland/archive/2007/05/15/memories-guesses-and-apologies.aspx) is a good starting point.

In normal operation, we would never have two wallet services doing the same work.  They might be *sharing* the work (in much the same way that the Book Services share the work from the load balancer).

One way that you might share the work is to assign to each message a unique number; top wallet processes the odd numbered messages and ignores the even numbered messages, bottom wallet processes the even numbered messages and ignores the odd numbered messages.

---

Of course, normal operation is what you want, but not necessarily what you get -- after all, [distributed systems are imperfect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacies_of_distributed_computing#The_fallacies).  For some kinds of problems, there are comfortable patterns - locking, or idempotent message handling -- and your system can continue to deliver business value.

For other kinds of problems, the answer is that some human being gets on the phone, and tells somebody else that there has been a mistake, and can we work things out?

Comment: I thinks I'm starting to get it. I mixed up event sourcing and domain events. Event communication beetwen services != event sourcing but because on most lectures in the internet those two are shown togheter it blended in my head as a single concept.

Comment: @Arczewski Absolutely.  Event Sourcing is really just a data persistence mechanism. It's about persisting a stream of "facts" about your domain (e.g. "CustomerSignedUp", "CustomerCreditLimitIncreased", "CustomerMovedAddress") and which can be "replayed" in order to build the current state of a domain aggregate (e.g. Customer, Sales Order, Product etc).  Nothing about Event Sourcing mandates that messages are sent across a network, however in reality, most Event Sourced systems are also distributed systems and so also communicate asynchronously with messages.

Comment: @VoiceOfUnreason not sure why literature sucks. I optimistically assume that my book has enough content about Event Sourcing. In the Event Store blog, we published a few articles explaining what Event Sourcing is. I agree that many blog posts out there don't do a favour to people by telling weird things about Event Sourcing, but that's also valid about other things.